# Flutter How to partially block touch event inside GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I have a listview with every Item wrap inside a GestureDetector to be clickable, but is there a way to have a portion of the Item view to be not clickable? Thanks

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      ...
    },
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
          child: SizedBox( height: 40,
            child: Container( 
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text("Hello world"), // want to make the text area not clikable
            ),
          ),
          someOtherWidgets...
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu well the  `...` parts seem to be placeholders for actual code

Answer (score 0):

Yes then you have to take particular item click and it should be blank in that case, Example `InkWell` click and child `Text`

```
InkWell(
onTap: () {
  ...
},
behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
      child: SizedBox( height: 40,
        child: Container( 
          color: Colors.green,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){}
            ,
              child:Text("PBX",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),)), // you can use like this text will be blank click 
        ),
      ),
      someOtherWidgets...
  ],
),
```

Comment: I have no idea who did that. for your answer, I actually thought about that too but was thinking maybe there is a more elegant way.